# How to damage control after an internal oppurtunity got nullified due to hiring freeze?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, internal-transfer

I was interviewing for an internal mobility role at my firm (a big financial company). The interviews went quite well and it was all but certain I would get the role. I had to do a fair bit of convincing with my management to get them onboard, essentially telling them the role is my first choice, and I'm willing to be embarrassed if it doesn't work out - I was pretty sure it would.

Now after all rounds of interviews, I've been told there is a hiring freeze. So I am stuck in a role where the management really doesn't hold me in much regard in terms of growth, although my performance is good.

My question - what is the conversation I should have with my management? Should I be open to the possibility that the role may open again in the future? I really regard it as perfect for myself.

Edit - Thanks everyone for your inputs! Though unfortunately I just got laid off.

Comment: We can't really predict if the role will open up again. The only think I would encourage is for you to keep looking for opportunities at other companies.

Comment: Is the "hiring freeze" for the whole company, for the department you want to go to or for the department you come from?

Comment: Hiring freezes are often related to cashflow or upcoming redundancies. Identifying the scope and reason behind the freeze may help you to judge if the role will open up again. If the freeze only applies to this one role then consider that it might be that they've actually just decided that they don't want to hire you for this role (perhaps because your current manager complained loudly enough).

Comment: Why do you need to do damage control? You thought you saw an opportunity that would be good for both you and the company; that's a good thing. It didn't work out; that's nobody's fault.

Comment: @Philipp freeze seems to be with the department I was going to go into.

Answer (score 10):

If you super want that role, you have two options:
Find that role in another company.
Or make sure that this role will open for you in your current company asap.
If you do that, you risk that your current management will be disappointed and sidelines you.
If they cant give you written promises, be aware that it could take years to open, or indeed never open. Plans change.

The alternative is to speak with your current management that you really wanna grow, and about all the options they see for you in the short/mid-term future.
That way you signal you accepted that the other role isn't available, and that you actively plan to improve where you are.

Answer (score 5):

> I had to do a fair bit of convincing with my management to get them
> onboard, essentially telling them the role is my first choice, and I'm
> willing to be embarrassed if it doesn't work out - I was pretty sure
> it would.

If you didn't have to tell your current manager about the interviews you shouldn't have done so.

If the corporate process guaranteed that your current manger would be told before you accepted the new position, the company should reconsider their internal transfer system.

Employees should never be put in this situation, they may have cost the company a good employee.

> My question - what is the conversation I should have with my management?

Depends on the goal:

- keep my current job until I find an external one
- keep my current job until a similar internal transfer opens up.
- I have learned my lesson, and will never try for an internal transfer.

Pick your words to match the picture you want to paint for your current manager, without giving away your real plan if you will be leaving soon.

If this plan to lie worries you, just remember that if the company put you into this position, they should expect you to be trying to minimize the damage to your job.

> Should I be open to the possibility that the role may open again in
> the future? I really regard it as perfect for myself.

Sure it might open again. You might still want it. But you need to find a way to not alert your current manager.